# Create an array of dates and a count of those dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am trying to creating an array I can pass to GCharts to display date vs the number of times that date occurs.

I can create a hash ok, but how can you create a simple array with date and count.

I tried converting my code to an array (`to_a`) but the array is too nested.  @results is an active record relation, it contains an array of records.

```
@values =  @results.map{|x| [x.start_time.strftime('%F')]}.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |a, b| a[b] += 1; a }

Hash (5 elements)
["2016-03-07"] = 3
["2016-03-06"] = 4
["2016-03-05"] = 10
["2016-03-04"] = 1
["2016-03-03"] = 22
```

But I would like an array like this: each element in the array should have 2 elements.

```
[0] should have ["2016-03-07"][3]
[1] should have ["2016-03-06"][4]
[2] should have ["2016-03-05"][10]
```

etc

This is the array I want, but I just need to perform a count of the dates and have the count as the second element in the array:

```
@results.map{|x| [x.start_time.strftime('%F'), x.build_number]}
```

This is how I did it, I am sure there is a better way without the loop:

```
builds_per_day =  @results.map{|x| [x.start_time.strftime('%F')]}.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |a, b| a[b] += 1; a }

    @array_of_builds_per_day =[]
    builds_per_day.each do |key, value|
      @array_of_builds_per_day<< [key[0].to_s,value]
      end
```

Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Just add `.to_a` on the end

Comment: What is yours expected output?

Comment: Its just results from the model, so active record relation?

Comment: When providing an example, you should specify all variables (i.e. `@results = [...]`). Otherwise we're unable to run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand your question properly, but if you want

```
{"2016-03-13"=>19, "2016-03-14"=>1}
```

instead of

```
{["2016-03-13"]=>19, ["2016-03-14"]=>1}
```

try this:

```
@results.map{|x| x.start_time.strftime('%F')}.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |a, b| a[b] += 1; a }
```

**Update**:

With the new info, this code should do the job:

```
@results.group_by{|x| x.start_time.strftime('%F')}.map{|k,v| [[k], [v.size]] }
```

it will return something like

```
[ 
  [["2016-03-13"], [19]], 
  [["2016-03-14"], [1]]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your question correctly but if I do then I believe calling to_a yields something like

```
[["2016-03-07",3],["2016-03-06", 4]]
```

and you would like

```
["2016-03-07",3,"2016-03-06", 4]
```

instead?
If so, calling .to_a.flatten is what you want